# CSS for specific pages

Tags: theming, 8

How do I add CSS styles for a specific page?

For example, I want the `<body>` background color on a specific page to be different from the background color used on the front page.
I've looked into `hook_theme_preprocess()`, but I am confused on how I should implement it.

Comment: In most cases you can make use of body classes.

Comment: If you are trying to style specific nodes then [Code per Node module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cpn) can help you do that via the Drupal UI, without writing any custom PHP code.

Comment: This module is only available for Drupal 7, the question was regarding Drupal 8, as it was tagged with the `8` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find totorial for adding specific CSS to specif page to the following links.

1. [Drupal 8 Theming Fundamentals, Part 1](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1), but it is describing how to add specific CSS to front page.
2. [Drupal8 attaching libraries to specific pages](http://www.appcreator.com/node/139), to add the specific CSS to specific node you need to follow tutorial on this page .

To give you example I am explaining with bartik theme for easy understanding.

I have created a css file cssfile.css and pasted at path `css/cssfile.css` Now this CSS file I want to use in one case to only front page and in otehr case to only specific node.

#### Step 1: Adding a library to the theme

Add the following code to *bartik.libraries.yml*.

```
css-filling: 
  css:
    theme:
      css/cssfile.css: {}
```

The library name I used is *css-filling*, but you can use other names.

#### Step 2: Adding the CSS styles to a specific page

Step 2a: Adding CSS styles only to the front page

The following code in the *bartik.theme* adds the library to the front page.

```
function bartik_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['is_front']) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'bartik/css-filling';
  }
}
```

Step 2b: Adding CSS styles to a specific node

The following code adds the library only to a specific node.

```
function bartik_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node) {
    if ($node->id() == 3) {
      $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'bartik/css-filling';
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code the important thing is path, *bartik* comes from the theme name and *css-filling* comes from step 1.

Comment: I apply css to individual pages by embedding them in the source of the page via <style type="text/css"> *css code* </style>

Comment: @PatriciaW this is not the best approach. Use {{ attach_library(“theme-name/library-name”) }} instead

Answer (score 4):

Most Drupal themes still provide enough classes on the body tag to allow you to target the front page separately from all others.  Stable (the most basic of base-themes in Drupal 8 core) provides `front` on the front page and `not-front` on all others.

But you can load style sheets conditionally if that's important to your project.  The complete details [are available here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme), but the short version is that you can define a library in your theme and then attach the library in whatever html.twig file you need to ensure that libraries loads for:

```
{{ attach_library('mytheme/mylibrary') }}
```

Comment: Would I have to make multiple html.twig files depending on the node for this to work?

Comment: I would always look first at adding extra body classes to enable you to specify background colours based on whatever makes the page distinct.

Answer (score 0):

To add custom style for a specific page. Here I'm adding it for login page, register page.

**File:- mytheme.theme**

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  // \Drupal::logger('mytheme')->error('Start');
    $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
    if (in_array($route_name, ['user.login', 'user.pass', 'user.register'])) {
        $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/login';
    }
}
```

Following content are same as the [@CodeNext answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/221522).

**File:- mytheme.info.yml**

**Doc:** https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml

```
libraries:
  - mytheme/global-styling
  - bootstrap5/bootstrap5-js-latest
libraries-override:
  bootstrap5/global-styling: false
```

Note: I'm not adding *login library* in mytheme.info.yml

**File:- mytheme.libraries.yml**

```
login:
  css:
    theme:
      css/login.css: { minified: true }
```

Answer (score -1):

In Drupal 7, there is a class like page-node-NID (with NID replaced by the node ID of the node being viewed) added to the  tag so we can easily add CSS styles to specific nodes for example:

```
body.page-node-NID{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Drupal 8 is missing this core D7 functionality, but now there is a module for that, its called [Body node ID class](https://www.drupal.org/project/body_node_id_class)